# How to post credentials using POSTMAN client to create a cookie based session

Tags: rest, authentication, cookies, jira, postman

I am using postman client to make REST calls to JIRA API. It says "POST your credentials to http://jira.example.com:8090/jira/rest/auth/1/session" to get SESSION. I tried posting with Form-data, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, raw etc. Nothing worked. which is the right way to do that.

Here is the tutorial i am following: https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-cookie-based-authentication

Comment: did you try wirh `raw` and setting `content-type` to `application/json`? what response do you get?

Comment: i got "You are not authenticated. Authentication required to perform this operation."

Comment: and you are posting to this? `http://localhost:8090/jira/rest/auth/1/session`

Comment: You'll need to get the session cookie first, then add the session cookie to every subsequent request. So the first thing to do would be to check you can authenticate correctly

Comment: Funny. I am trying to authenticate (get session cookie)

Comment: just looked into Jira documentation, apparenlty it also supports HTTP baasic authentication, maybe give that a try (could be that your jira instance is only configured to use that) https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-basic-authentication

Comment: Using basic involves authentication for every request(performance issue). so i decided to go for cookie based

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125561/discussion-between-lokesh-cherukuri-and-michele-ricciardi).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're using postman, I'm assuming you're in a dev environment. In this case, it might be simpler to get going with the auth header, which is a base-64 encoded username/password. From the documentation [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiracloud/authentication-and-authorization-39990700.html):

> Supplying Basic Auth headers
>
> If you need to you may construct and send basic auth headers yourself. To do this you need to perform the following steps:
>   Build a string of the form username:password
>   Base64 encode the string
>   Supply an "Authorization" header with content "Basic " followed by the encoded string. For example, the string "fred:fred" encodes to "ZnJlZDpmcmVk" in base64, so you would make the request as follows.
>
> `curl -D- -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic ZnJlZDpmcmVk" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://kelpie9:8081/rest/api/2/issue/QA-31"`

In the `Headers` section of Postman, add `Authorization` with `Basic <base64-encoded-username:password>`

Don't forget to also add the header `Content-Type` as `application/json`

(You can use [base64encode.org](https://www.base64encode.org/) to quickly encode your username/password).
**Don't forget to put the string in as username-colon-password (`username:password`)**

Answer (score 3):

If you are on the same UI as I for postman, click Authorization, select an auth type (I used basic auth succesfully), and then enter your credentials.  Next click over to the body tab, select raw, and on the drop down menu on the right choose JSON(applications/json), and supply the body as normal.

That is the first hurdle. The next hurdle which may be hit (and the one I am stuck on) is that once your basic-auth gets accepted, JIRA will deny access as part of Cross Site Request Forgery checks (XSRF) with a code 403.  I have a ticket open right now seeing if there is a possible workaround to post and put from postman, because using postman and newman would be much much simpler than building an entire plugin which I have to jump through a bunch of hoops to access.

Answer (score 0):

With Postman can simply add `withCredentials:true` to your request header section.